# Update ordering of related model at runtime in django

Tags: django, runtime, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I do not want to apply permanent ordering with the default ordering in `Meta`. I would rather update it at run time and than access it from templates. Is there a more elegant way than the following?

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    question = super().get_object(queryset)
    question.choice_set.ordered = question.choice_set.order_by('-votes')
    return question
```

Because this will not update if the underlying objects changed.

Comment: you can do the ordering in your function where you are querying.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example of your models? Explain please better what do you mean by "update it at run time".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `order_by` method of the QuerySet?

Assuming you have a modell `Question`, which has some related model, let's call it `Answer`:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField()
    votes = models.IntegerField()

class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField()
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name="questions")
```

Then you can order your retrieved results like this:

```
q = Question.objects.order_by('-answer__votes')
```

This is everything done with Django tools, no need to create anything extra.